# Delete multiple rows in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a function to delete single rows on right click delete in a datagridview..

code:

```
  private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                var hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
                if (hti.RowIndex != -1)
                {
                    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Selected = true;
                }
            }          
    }

    private void DeleteRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Int32 rowToDelete = dataGridView1.Rows.GetFirstRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
            if (rowToDelete != -1)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowToDelete);
                dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
            }          
    }
```

but now I want to delete multiple rows on selection.
First I don't know why I cannot select multiple rows.
Second I want to delete multiple delete using the delete button and right click mouse delete.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit:
Take a look at your code.  You are setting the selected row depending on the results of the `HitTest` method.  The `DataGridView` property `SelectedRows` will determine which rows are selected.  Not sure why you need to execute a `HitTest`, but then again perhaps you haven't fully explained the desired functionality.

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
{
    var hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    if (hti.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        dataGridView1.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Make sure that the `MultiSelect` property is set to `true` on your datagrid.

Then, you can utilize the `SelectedRows` property in the event of your choice:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

Comment: the multiple select works.. but on right click delete... when i select multiple rows and right click it selects only one row... why is this happening

Comment: Have you checked the `SelectionMode` property of the datagrid?  Are you sure you are selecting the full row and not just a cell?

Comment: yes i am selecting the full row and not just a cell..where is the selection mode..?? thanks

Comment: my selection mode is row header select

Answer (score 3):

please take care the following case:

if you need to delete records in datagrid,
don't just store the rowIndex in datagrid, (instead you should store the corresponding keys in DB):

eg: I want to delete row 1 and 2 in datagrid, I stored their rowIndex in datagrid.
after row 1 is deleted in datagrid, data in row 2 will SHIFT UP to row 1, and
data in row 3 will SHIFT UP to row 2,
because you are using the datagrid rowIndex to locate what data to delete, therefore,
result: data1 and data3 will be deleted finally.

Answer (score 0):

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgShow.SelectedRows)
            {
                string id = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                int x = Convert.ToInt16(id);
                var del = context.ServicesPrice.Where(current => current.Id == x).FirstOrDefault();
                context.ServicesPrice.Remove(del);
            }
```

you can write instead of cells[4]: columns id in your DB.